# shell script to read file line by line does not work

Tags: bash, shell, unix

i have this master script

```
>loanIds
>log
>count
mkdir -p duplicates
rm -rf duplicates/*
for file  in x*
do
./getXmlData.sh $file &
done
```

Source for getXmlData.sh

```
cat $file | while read line
do
echo $file" | "$line
done
```

i have 40 files that start with letter x
each x* file has 1000 lines.

when i run the script, as you can see it will create 40 instances in the background and process each x* file

The problem i have is, ./getXmlData.sh does not echo all 1000 lines for each of those 40 files... for some files it echos all 1000 lines.. for some of them it echos only 10-15 lines

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you've not shown an assignment in your `getXmlData.sh` script, the problem is likely that you are passing `$file` in the calling script but you need to reference it as `$1` in the called script.  That is, you should be writing:

```
cat "$1" |
while read -r line
do
    echo "$1 | $line"
done
```

or (better — avoiding UUOC or Useless Use of `cat`):

```
while read -r line
do
    echo "$1 | $line"
done < "$1"
```

or something similar.  Indeed, we could even suggest:

```
sed "s%^%$1 | %" "$1"
```

This assumes that the file name doesn't contain a newline or a percent (but allows the name to include slashes, hence the use of `%` instead of `/` in the `s///` command).  Note that the file name is enclosed in double quotes each time it is used; this protects your script from file names containing spaces, etc.  Also note that the `echo` encloses `$line` (as well as `$1`) in double quotes; this preserves the spacing in the data, and avoids other [metacharacter expansions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415805/shell-script-to-read-file-line-by-line-does-not-work/25416099?noredirect=1#comment39647784_25416099) too.  If you really wanted all sets of multiples spaces or tabs converted to a single space, then the original formulation was OK, but that is seldom the desired result.

One other possibility: maybe after the loop, you should wait for all the children to complete.  You do that by telling the shell to:

```
wait
```

It won't progress further until its background processes terminate.

Comment: oops.. that was a typo.. it should be "cat $1". thanks for your suggestions

Comment: We can only debug what you show us; please be careful to show us what we need to debug (and not a random approximation to what we need to debug).  Copy'n'paste is more reliable than retyping.

Comment: @user1413813, `cat $1` is wrong; it needs to be `cat "$1"`, with the quotes, or filenames with spaces or glob characters will behave surprisingly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, ...coalescing runs of spaces or tabs to individual spaces is one thing; replacing [space]*[space] with a list of files in the current directory is another, and even less likely to be desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

try this way ->

```
file=$1
chmod 755 $file
exec <$file
while IFS= read -r
do
    echo "$file | $REPLY"
done
```

Or to avoid issues with "read" command, I came up with below logic which basically calculates the number of lines and prints it one by one using head/tail command ->

```
file=$1 
lines=`wc -l $file | cut -d" " -f1`
for ((i=1;i<=$lines;i++));
do
    line=`head -$i $file | tail -1`
    echo "$file | $line"
done
```

Comment: Needs more quotes; also, without changing `IFS`, it'll strip trailing whitespace rather than representing it correctly; also, without using the `-r` argument to read, it'll transform backslash-escape sequences into their referents (for instance, changing a literal `\t` into a tab character).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. I have added "-r" to take care of escape sequence. How to avoid trailing whitespace?

Comment: Put `IFS=` immediately before the `read`. (Also, that `head | tail` thing is insanely inefficient, and *also* strips trailing whitespace). So: `while IFS= read -r line; do`

Comment: ...incidentally, not specifying an explicit variable (and using the implicit destination of `REPLY`) will also have the effect of disabling the implicit trailing-whitespace stripping. So: `while read -r; do echo "$file | $REPLY"; done`